# Generate Invertible Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

I would like to generate 200 invertible functions.

Currently, I pass a function to `Solve`, which solves the function symbolically with respect to a specified variable. 
For instance,

```
Solve(x/(1 + x) == y, x)
```

returns

```
expression(list(x == y/(1 - y)))
```

I take this expression and switch the x's and y's:

```
y = x/(1 - x)
```

However, I want to make sure that I only pass invertible functions to Solve. There are no constraints on the functions, though I'd like to include a good variety of trigonometric functions and exponents. I'm trying to provide middle and high school students with diverse practice with inverting functions.

Is there a way to manipulate  $y=a(x+b)^{(2n+1)}+c$ or $y=\frac{a+bx} {c+dx}+d$ so that it involves trig functions like $cos$/$sin$/$tan$?

Comment: A function is not just an expression but defined on an interval.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to explain a bit better what you want here, in particular what is the goal and what are the constraints (if any) on the functions? Otherwise, take the real functions $y = a (x+b)^{2n+1} + c$ or $y=\frac{a+b x}{c+ d x}+d$ for any constants $a,b,c,d$ and integer $n$.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak thank you for the advice! Please let me know if anything I added doesn't make sense

Comment: Trigonometric functions are periodic, hence essentially non-invertible.